# Mongoose FindOneAndUpdate not Updating when Pushing an Object to a Nested Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

When trying to push to a nested array it's not updating in my database with the following code:

```
const obj = {
      key: key,
      user: user,
      description: description,
      date: Date.now(),
      guildId: guildId,
    };

    const guild = await this.GuildModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      { guildId: guildId },
      { $push: { 'guildData.commandLogs': obj } },
    );
```

My schema:

```
const GuildSchema = {
  guildId: { type: String },
 
  guildData: {
    commandLogs: [CommandLogsSchema],
  },
```

Any idea why my database isn't updating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might have some typos in your model:

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
 const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
 
 const GuildSchema = new Schema({   guildId: { type: String },  
 guildData: {
    commandLogs: [CommandLogsSchema],   })
```

in your controller, the filter condition that you're passing is not clear, which guildId you are using? also when you call the guildData.commandLogs field to update it you are missing brackets

```
const filter = { guildId: heretheactualId };
const update = {  { $push: { commandLogs: obj} }};

  const guild = await this.GuildModel.findOneAndUpdate(
       filter,
       update,
    );
```

this is not going to fix your problem because I don't know what kind of errors you're having or your database model but these tips can already help.